# In ExpressionEngine 2, is it possible to use the same 'page' template for multiple pages?

Tags: templates, url, expressionengine

Let me clarify: I am building a relatively simple brochure site that has multiple sections that I would like to use the same 'template'. For example: http://example.com/section1 & http://example.com/section2. I would also like these two sections to use the same 'view' template for their individual entry pages, for example on http://example.com/section1/item1 or http://example.com/section2/item2/.

Is this possible? I am very new to EE & have been reading about lots of ways to change url structure etc but nothing quite like what I'm asking. I am also aware that my solution could be achieved by creating two template groups with identical index templates with them but that seems rather silly.

P.S. I know my channel settings might be relevant so please let me know what they should be in order to answer this.

Many thanks

Zander

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, and you've got a few options.

The first is to use [Structure](http://buildwithstructure.com/). Structure allows you to use the same page templates across multiple pages (ie http://example.com/section1 and  http://example.com/section2).  This is probably your best bet.

The second option is to use the Pages Module that comes with ExpressionEngine.

The third option is to make your index template a simple 'router'. It would go something like this:

```
 {if segment_2 == 'item1'}
     {embed="template_group/template_name" entry_id="4"}
 {if:elseif segment_2 == 'item2'}
     {embed="template_group/template_name" entry_id="3"}
 {if:elseif segment_1 == 'section2'}
     {embed="template_group/template_name" entry_id="2"}
 {if:elseif segment_1 == 'section1'}
     {embed="template_group/template_name" entry_id="1"}
 {/if}
```

This will look at the URL segments and then embed the same template for each, and pass it the entry ID which you can use in your `{exp:channel:entries}` tag to display the content from the appropriate entry.

Comment: I'd just add that if you're going to do conditionals like the above, that http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/switchee would probably be useful.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm not sure which answer I'm going to go with but this is a very useful snippet in any case

Comment: The embed option would solve the problem, but it's not really a good option from a performance  standpoint. Each time you call an embed the template parser runs again - it would be much more performant to use the Pages or Structure Module.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is possible. Checkout the Pages module.

The Pages module will allow you select the URL as well as the template. When installed the Pages module will add a new 'pages' tab to the edit screen. Make sure you are not setting the dynamic parameter to 'no' in your {exp:channel:entries} tag pair.

There are other solutions to this problem, but this is the most straight forward.

Comment: Thank you, it makes perfect sense. Now I have to decide which answer to go with...